# Rotation behaviour like UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, rotation, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

i need to create my own ImagePicker since the UIImagePickerController is not able to suite my needs. This ImagePicker should look and behave like the original UIImagePickerController but have an UIView between the camera preview and the buttons so that i can display images (e. g. a grid) as overlay image.

To do this, i will use the AV Foundation Framework which is, for whatever reason, easier to understand (for me) than the rotating behaviour which i would like to achieve. And here is the problem:
In the original UIImagePickerController, the "take photo" button always stays next to the iPhones home button but its content rotates to the right orientation. The "flash" and "switch camera" buttons stay always to the top edge.

How can i achieve such a behaviour? How many ViewControllers / Views do i need for this and how would the hierarchy look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be done in one view ;)
reasonable to me sounds one per button and a parent view .... so 4!?

apply a transform the view (CGAffineTransformRotate) to counter the devices rotation

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

Comment: Till now, i only have experience with rotating the whole interface. I'm stuck on how i could "glue" the photo button next to the home button of the phone no matter in which direction the phone is rotated while other views rotate just as i would expect it if i rotate the whole interface. Also the container holding all views together should not rotate i think..

Comment: Okay, not exactly the answer i would like to have but it pointed me definately to the right direction. :)

What i have done is the following:

-Create a ViewController which only supports portrait orientation

-Register for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

-When orientation is changed, determine orientation with [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation

-Set buttons transform property based on the orientation (e. g. CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0 / 180.0) for portrait, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 90 / 180.0) for landscape left)

Comment: That seems cool. make it an answer, accept that and I make a comment of mine! - yes :) now you did it and thats even better. :D